# How can I set the colours in libass subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

ffmpeg allows you to pass parameters through to the subtitling library, libass. For example:

```
# this is wrong
# 0057b8=blue, ffd700=gold
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf "subtitles=russian.srt:force_style='Fontname=Gill\ Sans\ MT,Fontsize=20,borderstyle=3,outline=3,OutlineColour=0057b8,PrimaryColour=ffd700'" -y rc1.mp4
```

If you try to set the colours, you will probably get them wrong on the first attempt:

[image: black text on dark red]

Answer (score 2):

1. The colour format used by libass is [really weird](http://www.tcax.org/docs/ass-specs.htm): `&HAABBGGRR` (alpha, blue, green, red). This is backwards from the standard web ordering, `&HRRGGBBAA` (red, blue, green).
2. The alpha is inverted: `00` is fully opaque, and `FF` is fully transparent.
3. You *have* to spell it the British way. `PrimaryColor` and `OutlineColor` will fail without an error.

The correct form of the command line above is

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf "subtitles=russian.srt:force_style='Fontname=Gill\ Sans\ MT,Fontsize=20,borderstyle=3,outline=3,OutlineColour=&H00b85700,PrimaryColour=&H0000d7ff'" -y rc1.mp4
```

[image: gold on blue]